# Trying to convert simple execution stored procedure to postgres function - can't get CURRVAL('table_seq') to function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, migrating

The MySQL Stored Procedure was:

```
     BEGIN
     set @sql=_sql;
     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
     set _ires=LAST_INSERT_ID();
     END$$
```

I tried to convert it to:

```
     BEGIN  
     EXECUTE _sql;
     SELECT INTO _ires CURRVAL('table_seq');
     RETURN;
     END;
```

I get the error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  relation "table_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT CURRVAL('table_seq')
                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT CURRVAL('table_seq')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "myexecins" line 4 at SQL statement
In statement:
SELECT myexecins('SELECT * FROM tblbilldate WHERE billid = 2')
```

The query used is for testing purposes only. I believe this function is used to get the row id of the inserted or created row from the query. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create tables with serial columns, sequences are, by default, named as `tablename_columnname_seq`, but it seems that you're trying to access `tablename_seq`. So with a table called `foobar` and primary key column `foobar_id` it ends up being `foobar_foobar_id_seq`.

By the way, a *cleaner* way to get the primary key after an insert is using the `RETURNING` clause in `INSERT`. E.g.:

```
_sql = 'INSERT INTO sometable (foobar) VALUES (123) RETURNING sometable_id';
EXECUTE _sql INTO _ires;
```

Comment: you can use the pg_get_serial_sequence function to avoid having to deal with the naming convention of the sequence

Comment: yes... but does pg_get_serial_sequence() work if you do not know the sql in the _sql variable?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is saying that there is no sequence called "table_seq". Are you sure that that is the right name? The name you would use would depend on what is in `_sql` as each `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` gets its own sequence, you can also define sequences and wire them up by hand.

In any case, `lastval()` is a closer match to MySQL's `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, `lastval()` returns the most recently returned value from any sequence in the current session:

> [**lastval**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-sequence.html)
>   Return the value most recently returned by nextval in the current session. This
>   function is identical to currval, except that instead of taking the sequence name
>   as an argument it fetches the value of the last sequence used by nextval in the
>   current session. It is an error to call lastval if nextval has not yet been called
>   in the current session.

Using `lastval()` also means that you don't have to worry about what's in `_sql`, unless of course it doesn't use a sequence at all.

Comment: Perfect..because i don't want to go back and find everytime this function is being called and tell it to send the table name and column as a parameter along with the query.